# After match define new characteristic

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets I want to connect. 
The connection characteristics can be found in the sheet "Type" in column A and in the sheet "Data" in column J.

Is there a possibility, after a match has been found here, that the new characteristic is defined in the sheet "Data" in column B in the same process?

Since my English is not the best, here is an illustration of what I want to do in the sheet "Data":

match found in Column J:
[image: match found]

Column B now specifies that the value is updated in column L.:
[image: Column B now specifies that the value is updated in column L.]

```
Sub test()

lastrow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = Worksheets("Type").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Set sh = Sheets("Data")
Set sb = Sheets("Type")

With sh

For j = 2 To lastrow
found = False
    i = 2
    Do Until i = lastRow2
            If Sheets("Data").Range("J" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("A" & i).Value Then

'Something should happen here

            Sheets("Data").Range("L" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Is there a way to execute this function without an additional auxiliary column?

The alternative would be to run an Vlookup from the sheet "Data" to the Sheet "Type":

Sheet Data before:
[image: Sheet "DATA" before]

Sheet Type before:
[image: Sheet "Type" before]

Sheet Type after I use VLOOKUP and insert Column B based on the findings in Column J:
[image: Sheet Type after I use VLOOKUP and insert Column B based on the findings in Column J]

Sheet Data after I run the following code below to match the new Column E in "Type" with the Column B in Data to insert the values from Column D (Sheet"Type") in Column L in Sheet Data:
[image: 4]

The code for the last step would look like:

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = Worksheets("Type").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Set sh = Sheets("Data")
Set sb = Sheets("Type")

With sh

For j = 2 To lastrow

    i = 2
    Do Until i = lastRow2
    If Sheets("Data").Range("B" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("E" & i).Value Then
            Sheets("Data").Range("L" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

Next j
End With
```

Is there a possible way to avoid the Vlookup beforehand in order to improve the performance?

Comment: does your code work? It's not easy to see what you want/ What's the final result you are hoping to see?

Comment: basically I want the following: If Sheets("Data").Range("J" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("A" & i).Value Then 'Set the Value in Column B as the new matching-variable and everywhere where Sheets("Data").Range("B" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("D" & i) based on the finding in Sheets("Data").Range("J" & j). I know its kinda hard to explain in my native language also.. The alternative would be that I do a Vlookup in the sheet "Type" first with Column F in Data and insert the Values from Column B there and afterwards just execute my code above as following:

Comment: If Sheets("Data").Range("B" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("E" & i).Value Then
            Sheets("Data").Range("L" & j).Value = Sheets("Type").Range("D" & i).Value

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Unformatted code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: hey, I edited the main post to hopefully make the question a little bit understandable

Comment: Sounds like you need another loop to perform the function of the vlookup. you may want to store results of this search in an array or collection, to avoid loopception